# How not to redirect page on ajax submit codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

So, i have a following ajax code and controller code, my problem is i want to insert comment withouth refreshing the page and not redirecting to another page, and it seems that whenever i hit btnCommentSubmit it is redirecting me to my controller page, how to prevent that?

 Ps. The insertion is working

//AJAX CODE

```
$('#btnComment').click(function(e){

            var comment_identifier = $(this).data("value");
            var comment_by = $(this).data("id");
            $('#formAddComment').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>Discussion/addComment/'+comment_identifier+"/"+comment_by);
        });

        $('#btnCommentSubmit').click(function(){
            var url = $('#formAddComment').attr('action');
            var addCommentTxt = $('#addCommentTxt').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: url,
                data: {addCommentTxt:addCommentTxt},
                success: function(){
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('Could not add data');
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

//Controller code

```
public function addComment(){
        $cIden = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $cBy = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $data = array(
            "comment_identifier" => $cIden,
            "comment_by" => preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z-]/', ' ', $cBy),
            "comment" => $this->input->post('addCommentTxt'),
            "comment_at" => time() 
        );  

        if ($this->Crud_model->insert('comments',$data)) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `e.preventDefault()` in the beginning of your function:

```
$('#btnCommentSubmit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  ...

}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of e?

Comment: e is the caller button or anchor I should say, you are preventing the default behavior of anchor button which is redirection. try it if it did not work please add a comment

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use jQuery form plugin. It submit form to our controller without any page refresh/redirect. I use it all the time.

**https://jquery-form.github.io/form/**

**Example usage:**

```
    $('#form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            //just optional confirmation
            if (!confirm('Are you sure want to submit this comment?')) return false;
            show_loading();
        },
        success: function(status) {
            hide_loading();
            if (status == true) {
                alert('success');
            } else {
                alert('Could not add data');
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript:void(0);` like `href="javascript:void(0);"`